# Removing Children from a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

```
for(int i = 0; i < stackPanel.Children.Count; i++)
{
     stackPanel.Children.Remove(stackPanel.Children[i]);
}
int x  = stackPanel.Children.Count();
```

After running the above code. The controls are still on the screen. Then x equals 33. So how do I really remove the children?

Comment: Try `stackPanel.Children.Clear()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know exactly what your code is doing, never mind explain its behavior with certainty.

However, here are some observations:

1. Based on the code you posted, I would expect that *some* children *are* removed. But because you are removing children at the same time you are varying the index used to identify the children to remove, you are skipping half the children. E.g. when `i` is 0, you remove the first child. But doing so causes the second child to now be the first child. Then you increment `i`. So the next time through the loop, you don't remove what was originally the second child, you remove what was originally the third child. And so on.
   You could address this by starting your index at the end, and working backwards. Or by just always removing the first child, at index `0`, until the collection is empty. Either way, you can also improve efficiency by using the `RemoveAt()` method, which removes an element at a specific index, rather than forcing the collection to search until finding the element.
   Of course, there's also the `Clear()` method. So if you want to remove all of the elements at once, you can use that instead of writing the loop yourself.
2. You really shouldn't be manipulating the `UIElementCollection` yourself in the first place. If you have dynamic elements like this, you should instead create a view model class to represent each element in the `StackPanel`, create instances of that class and add them to e.g. an `ObservableCollection<T>`, and then bind that collection to the `ItemsSource` of an `ItemsControl` that uses a `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanel` (which `ItemsControl` does by default).
   Having done that, you then just manipulate the collection as needed to add/remove/rearrange elements. Of course, doing so in a way to avoids the mistake you've made here. :)

Comment: Your 100% correct. Sometimes I just don't do things the right way because I'm not aware of the other options. I'm going to follow your 2nd point. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[`stackPanel.Children`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children(v=vs.110).aspx) returns  a [UIElementCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can just use `Clear()` like this :

```
stackPanel.Children.Clear()
```

Comment: How did I miss that! Thank you so much.

Comment: Marked it as the answer but since my points are to low It doesn't publicly display it.

Comment: No worries, glad I helped !

Comment: Could you also explain why they cannot be removed one by one?

Comment: @lv.programmer are you sure that you marked it as answer (green check sign) and not just tried to upvote (arrow up)? You should be able to mark an answer to your question, no matter your reputation points. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

> Could you also explain why they cannot be removed one by one?

Because you are modifying the same collection that you iterate over. So when you remove the element at index 0 and then increment the loop variable to 1, there is new item at index 0 that will never be removed.

You could solve this by iterating backwards. This works:

```
for (int i = stackPanel.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    stackPanel.Children.Remove(stackPanel.Children[i]);
}
int x = stackPanel.Children.Count;
```

Or you could just call the `stackPanel.Clear()` method as suggested by @StanleyS.